# Assignment operator, map and promises. What's wrong with that code ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, assignment-operator

I was doing some stuff and I ran into a problem that I can't understand.
I simplified the code to get that:

```js
function somePromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(1);
    });
}

async function main() {
    let count = 0;
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const promises = arr.map(async () => {
        count += await somePromise();
    })
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(count);
}

main().then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

What result do you expect ?

> 1
>   Done

is logged.

When I change

```
count += await somePromise();
```

to

```
const nb = await somePromise();
count += nb;
```

I get

> 5
>   Done

what I expected for the first time.

Can you help me to find what is wrong ? I don't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the interpreter comes across the `await`, it will pause the function until the resolution of the Promise. Even if the Promise resolves immediately, the function will only resume during the next microtask. In contrast, the array is iterated through *immediately*, synchronously. When you do

```
const promises = arr.map(async () => {
    count += await somePromise();
})
```

After the array is iterated through, but *before* the `await`s have resolved, the "current" value of `count` which is taken for use by the `+=` is retrieved *before* the `await` resolves - and the value of `count` before then is 0. So, it looks to the interpreter as if there are 5 separate statements:

```
count += await somePromise();
count += await somePromise();
count += await somePromise();
count += await somePromise();
count += await somePromise();
```

which resolve to something like

```
const currentValueOfCount = count;
count = currentValueOfCount + await somePromise();
count = currentValueOfCount + await somePromise();
count = currentValueOfCount + await somePromise();
count = currentValueOfCount + await somePromise();
count = currentValueOfCount + await somePromise();
```

So, each time, the right-hand side of the `=` resolves to `0 + 1`, so at the end of the loop, `count` is only 1.

If you're interested where this is described in the specification, look at the semantics for [assignment operators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation). Where `+=` is one of the `AssignmentOperator`s, the following syntax:

> LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression

does:

> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. **Let lval be ? GetValue(lref).**
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> 4. **Let rval be ? GetValue(rref).**
> 5. Let op be the @ where AssignmentOperator is @=.
> 6. Let r be the result of applying op to lval and rval as if evaluating the expression lval op rval.

See how `lval` is retrieved *immediately*, before the right-hand side of the operator is evaluated. (If `lval` had been retrieved *after* the right-hand side, the `AssignmentExpression`, is evaluated, the results would have been 5, as you're expecting)

Here's an example of this behavior *without* asynchronous operations:

```js
let num = 5;
const fn = () => {
  num += 3;
  return 0;
}
num += 2 + fn();
console.log(num);
```

Above, the `num += 2 + fn();` retrieves `num` as `5` immediately for use in `+=`, then calls `fn()`. Although `num` is reassigned inside `fn`, it doesn't have any effect, because the value of `num` has already been retrieved by the outer `+=`.

---

With your working code, when you do

```
const nb = await somePromise();
count += nb;
```

This will put the resolve value of `somePromise` into the `nb` variable, and *then* `count += nb;` will run. This behaves as expected because the "current" value of `count` used for `+=` is retrieved *after* the Promise resolves, so if a prior iteration reassigned `count`, it'll be successfully taken into account by the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your impressive detailed response! I understand now